# Log4j conflicts with commons logging in a Spring RESTful integration on tomcat 6

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, log4j, apache-commons

I am trying to integrate Spring RESTful service in my project which already uses log4j. Log4j is conflicting with commonslogging and not initializing the service. I am using commons logging to compile spring jar.

Comment: How do you say they are conflicting? commons.logging is just a facade to some logging APIs, including Log4j.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh http://radio-weblogs.com/0122027/2003/08/15.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved by including log4j.xml in my classes folder.
With all research on this topic, I come to know that jar conflict issue is with Webspehere not with Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

If your using Maven try 
<`scope> provided</scope>` for log4j transitive dependencies.